# Compute distances in kmeans Lloyds algorithm

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to compute the distance between each point of matrix `X` (shape N,D) and matrix `mu` (shape K,D) using numpy:

```py
np.array([[np.linalg.norm(x - m) for m in mu] for x in X])
```

This is very slow. Is there a faster way to get the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can extend the dimensions of one matrix to a third dimension and then calculate the distance:

```py
np.linalg.norm(X - mu[:,None], axis=-1, ord=2).T
```